# How to bind object's property to another object's property? (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm making a graphic control class `Info` which should display some text on screen. The text is some object's string. I'd like to be able to get that object's latest value from within an instance of `Info` class.

```
class Info
{
    public string Text;
}

void Program()
{
    ClassA obj = new ClassA();
    obj.name = "Instance of ClassA";
    Info wind1 = new Info();
    wind1.Text = obj.name; // this just copies current value, but should be a reference or something 

    /* obj.name value changes several times before it's time to display it again */

    // Info window drawing method
    foreach (var item in Windows) // Windows is List<Info>
    Draw(item.Text); // this doesn't get the latest value
}
```

How should I change the code so I can get the latest string value from within the drawing section?

Comment: I'm sure the title doesn't make as much sense at it could. Feel free to edit if you know a better phrasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** If you need something that'll work for any type, you'll have to use delegates. For example:

```
class Info
{
    private Func<string> getText;

    public Info(Func<string> getText)
    {
        getText = getText;
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return getText();
        }
    }
}

void Program
{
    ClassA obj = new ClassA();
    obj.name = "Instance of ClassA";
    Info wind1 = new Info(() => obj.name);

    // Now do your stuff.
}
```

In this case, `Info` is given an *anonymous function* that returns a string. When you access its `Text` property, the function is evaluated to retrieve that string. How the string is retrieved, and where it comes from, is determined by the client code (i.e. the `Program` method). This way, `Info` doesn't rely on any particular type.

---

You could pass the `ClassA` object into your `Info` instance, so that it can get the value of`.name` itself.

Something like this, perhaps?

```
class Info
{
    public Info(ClassA obj)
    {
        TheObject = obj;
    }

    public ClassA TheObject
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return TheObject.name;
        }
    }
}

void Program
{
    ClassA obj = new ClassA();
    obj.name = "Instance of ClassA";
    Info wind1 = new Info(obj);

    // Now do your stuff.
}
```

Comment: Except it's not always ClassA's string. I'm looking for something even more universal.